# Input Checkbox + DataTables + Jquery sometimes returns "on" instead of input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am having a bug in production environment and cannot reproduce it in dev environment, so I thinks it's a matter of browsers.

I have a [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) filled up by server side proccessing and a custom column that is a checkbox, here's the simplified code:

```
$("#data-table").DataTable({        
    "serverSide" : true,
    "ajax" : {
        "url" : "/list",
        "dataSrc" : "data"
    },
    "columns" : [{
            "data" : function(row) {
                return '<input class="id-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="' + row.id + '">';
            },
            "class" : "text-center",
            "orderable" : false
        },{
            "data" : "name",
            "class" : "text-center",
            "orderable" : false
        }]
    });
```

Then I have some jQuery code than whenever a button is clicked, then get the selected items and post it to the backend server:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){

    var ids = [];

    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        ids.push(this.value);
    });

    if (ids.length == 0) {
        //POST Ajax request to server
    }
});
```

The thing is that sometimes the `ids` array is being filled with some ids, and some "on" word, so then my backend explodes as is waiting for an array of `Long`. Here's an example stacktrace:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long[]'; 
nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
For input string: "109287,109286,109273,108820,on,on"
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

Comment: It might have to do with `input[type=checkbox]:checked` as it is not unique and you could be getting a checkbox not related to what you need.

Comment: You could try `input[name^=ids]:checked` I believe that should work to make it more specific

Comment: Will add more specification to the selector.

Comment: I guess as last resort if possible you could return a checkbox and hidden input (the hidden input would contain your value) you could give both the input and checkbox same id (to make it easier to get the correct input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kodecount had commented, the problem was the presence of another input checkbox on the same page, solved by adding

```
input[name^=ids]:checked
```

Answer (score 1):

"on" will be the value of a checkbox which has no value attribute:

```
<input id="i" type="checkbox">
```

If you log a value of this input, you will get `"on"` at least in Firefox:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('i').value);
```

Check what HTML is generated by your script. Maybe, some checkboxes miss value attributes. Maybe, because the `row.id` is sometimes not present, as an idea.

Comment: Yeah, understand that, but as is the id of created entity, it's always present. At least in the model. I cannot reproduce if DataTable is returning sometimes no data.